React state gets updated but changes are not reflected in an event listener called programatically
This is a socket.io chat app, where I am trying to add a keyboard shortcut. I am listening for the "keydown" event and calling the button click listener function (which is also throttled) when the specific combination of keys are pressed.
The problem is that when the click listener is being called by the click event of a button it is working as expected but when the listener is triggered from the keydown listener, it doesn't have the updated values of the state due to which it returns without performing any action.
These are my state variables:
const [userID, setUserID] = useState<string>('');
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<TMessage[]>([]);
const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = useState<string>('');
const [room, setRoom] = useState<string | null>(null);

Then I wrote the click event listener:
const handleSubmitClick = throttle(() => {
    console.log('userID', userID, 'room', room, 'message', messageInput.trim())
    /* When I click the button the listener logs:
       "userID 4W_o0nfOpLPknesfAA room 4W_o0nfOpLPknesfAA#NJsYxkxSVVfuQBzrAA message hello there"
       But when I use the keyboard shortcut the listener logs:
       "userID <empty string> room null message <empty string>"
    */

    if (!socket.connected || userID === '' || room === null || messageInput.trim() === '')
      return;

    const data: TMessage = { userID: socket.id!, message: messageInput.trim(), room: room };
    socket.emit(SocketEvents.CHAT_SEND, data);
  }, 400) // can run only after 0.4s after the last call

Then there is a Keydown listener:
function keyShortcuts(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'Enter') {
      handleSubmitClick();
    }
  }

The listener is being added inside a useEffect hook:
useEffect(() => {
  if (!socket.connected) {
    socket.connect();
  }
  function onConnect() {
    setUserID(socket.id!);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyShortcuts);
  }
  socket.on(SocketEvents.CONNECT, onConnect)

  return () => {
    socket.disconnect()
      .off(SocketEvents.CONNECT, onConnect)
  }
}, []);

Finally there is a button and textarea in the UI:
<textarea value={messageInput}
  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => setMessageInput(e.target.value)}
  disabled={disabled}
/>
<Primary label="Send" subtitle="(ctrl + Enter)"
  handleClick={handleSubmitClick} disabled={disabled}
/> {/* react button component */}


highly recommended reading here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/ Your specific problem is the empty depency array in the useEffect where you add the keydown handler, as that still references the handleSubmitClick from the very first render, with its empty userID. You need to be honest with all your dependencies, as explained in the article I linked.

The problem you have is due to closures. On initial render, when you are calling a useEffect hook to connect a socket and to add a window event listener - the function that is attached as window keydown event-listener is using the initial values of all the variables that are used inside of this function, those variables are not updated in any way by future rerenders.
And that is not happening with direct button click due to on each rerender - new state variables are set and the function handleSubmitClick is recreated, it does sees all the recent updates in that case and acts as expected.
One suggestion is to utilize a useRef hook to hold latest values of everything that you need for keydown event listener and handleSubmitClick. I found a small utility hook that acts as a useState one but also returns a ref variable:
function useStateWithRef<T>(
  initialValue: T
): [T, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>, React.MutableRefObject<T>] {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>(initialValue);
  const ref = useRef<T>(state);

  const setStateAndRef: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>> = (newState) => {
    if (typeof newState === "function") {
      setState((prevState) => {
        const computedState = (newState as (prevState: T) => T)(prevState);
        ref.current = computedState;
        return computedState;
      });
    } else {
      setState(newState);
      ref.current = newState;
    }
  };

  return [state, setStateAndRef, ref];
}

Usage:
const [userID, setUserID, userIDRef] = useStateWithRef<string>("");
const [messages, setMessages, messagesRef] = useStateWithRef<TMessage[]>([]);
const [messageInput, setMessageInput, messageInputRef] =
  useStateWithRef<string>("");
const [room, setRoom, roomRef] = useStateWithRef<string | null>(null);


const handleSubmitClick = throttle(() => {
  console.log(
    "userID",
    userIDRef.current,
    "room",
    room.current,
    "message",
    messageInput.current.trim()
  );
  // ...etc
}, 400);

Side note - you are not removing window keydown event listener in your useEffect, fix that please.
Another approach - wrap your functions keyShortcuts and handleSubmitClick with useCallback hooks and add a useEffect that will attach/detach keyShortcuts on state changed:
const lastSocketActionDateMsRef = useRef(0);

const handleSubmitClick = useCallback(() => {
  // can run only after 0.4s after the last call
  if (lastSocketActionDateMsRef.current + 400 > Date.now()) return;
  lastSocketActionDateMsRef.current = Date.now();

  console.log("userID", userID, "room", room, "message", messageInput.trim());

  if (
    !socket.connected ||
    userID === "" ||
    room === null ||
    messageInput.trim() === ""
  )
    return;

  const data = {
    userID: socket.id!,
    message: messageInput.trim(),
    room: room,
  };
  socket.emit("CHAT_SEND", data);
}, [userID, room, messageInput, socket]);

const keyShortcuts = useCallback(
  (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === "Enter") {
      handleSubmitClick();
    }
  },
  [handleSubmitClick]
);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", keyShortcuts);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyShortcuts);
  };
}, [keyShortcuts]);

Asuming handleSubmitClick has all the checks about socket status, userId, input value - if something is not set it will be a noop. Keydown event listener will be set and unset on each rerender when related states are changed. Just dont forget to remove window.addEventListener from the useEffect that is handling socket initialization.
But, there will be some issue with throttle function in that case - throttle and useCallback do not work nicely with each other, here is some details and workarounds and I'd suggest to remove a throttle and add a const lastSocketActionDateMsRef = useRef(0) and just check last execution time using this variable.

Thanks for explaining it so well! Follow up - we don't need to use useCallback hook with handleSubmitClick as it anyways gets updated on each rerender. Right?

@Yashv That depends, if you are using my last suggestion - if you remove useCallback from handleSubmitClick - then keyShortcuts will be updated (reference to the function) on every render, and on every render the useEffect that uses it to addEventListener will be reexecuted. But it will still be working, but using useCallback and useEffect with all the needed items in their dependency array usually helps with preventing bugs related to closures.

@Yashv as it anyways gets updated on each rerender the function itself - yes, it gets recreated on each rerender without useCallback and do see the new variables, but, it is just a reference, in one render the variable reference points to A, on next render - to B, and if some other function was executed and closure-captured reference for the function that points to A - it will not be automatically updated to B later. So at this point - two different versions of handleSubmitClick will exist, they will be using different state variables from different state snapshots.
